# How I can insert my HTML textbox value in marketing cloud data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have to save the Kaltura Video current time embed in landing page to marketing cloud data extension. I can fetch the current time through Evaluate function while closing the window like below but don't know how to store the "length" variable value in Data extension:

```
<script>

window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
kWidget.addReadyCallback(function(playerId)
{

var kdp= document.getElementById(playerId);
var length = (kdp.evaluate("{video.palyer.CurrentTime}")
);

}

);

alert (length);
}

</script>
```

Please somebody suggest me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
      <html>
      <head>
           <body>
         <form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" 
       method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="yourclientid" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="your DE extrenal key"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="https://www.google.co.in/Success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://exacttarget.com/Failed" />
        Email:<input type="text" name="Email"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to save the details while closing the window rather to create the submit form. Please check once my code and let me know if is there any other possible solution. @pkharries